# Lag compensator Design

Tags: control-system, bode-plot, compensation, phase-margin

I have a system with unity feedback using lag compensation to get \$10\%\$ overshoot and a settling time of \$1\;s\$. The continuous-time transfer function of the closed loop system is

$$g(s) =\frac{0.1 s^2 + 0.7 s + 1}{s^3 + 6.98 s^2 + 9.86 s + 19.8}$$

We are designing a lag compensator for above system. The problem is that gain margin of the above system is  infinite. In lag compensator we use

$$\mathrm{change\ in\ PM=PM \;(desired)- PM \;(actual)+10^\circ \; \small{(error\ approximation=10^\circ)}}.$$

Since \$\phi_m = -180^\circ + \text{small value}\$ and as a result we have to search for the new \$\omega_{gc}\$ near the \$-180^\circ\$ phase where the system is unavailable.

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Read your lecture notes again - design of a phase LAG compensator does not require the phase plot to pass through -180.

Comment: Thanx 4 ur response. CHANGE IN PM=PM(desired)-PM(ACTUAL)+TOL WHERE Tol. is about 6 to 10(deg.)                             and Phim=-180+CHANGE IN PM   =>which is near to 160(deg.)   where our phase plot doesn't exist.  doing it by MATLAB                           Hence I am unable  to search  for the new Wcg(gain cross over frequency)   i.e. my problem                                 so Plz help me find out  d answer  4 it.                         if i am wrong den plz rectify my view.                       THANKING U

Answer (score 1):

The denominator looks very suspicious and the coefficients seem cyclic in \$6, 9, 8\$, apart from the denominator constant! If the denominator were: \$s^3+6.98s^2+9.86s+69.8\$ then it would factorise to: \$(s+7)(s^2+10)\$. So my guess is a typo in the constant, 19.8

The TF numerator is \$0.1(s+5)(s+2)\$, and now the Bode plot can be sketched without recourse to Matlab or any other software.

As we know that the system is unity feedback, I suspect that the TF in the question is that of the closed loop system, and you need to determine the OLTF by equating to \$\dfrac{G}{1+G}\$ before you can do any work on control design. As it stands the system is critically stable (oscillatory). This can be determined from the denominator of the CLTF. Generally, if the denominator is

\$As^3 + Bs^2 + Cs + D,\$

then generally, for a stable system \$AD<BC\$, if \$BC=AD\$ the system is critically stable (or oscillatory) and if \$BC<AD\$ the system is unstable. So examining the denominator \$~s^3 + 7s^2 + 10s + 70\$, we see that BC=AD and hence critical, therefore there must be a term in \$(s^2 + \omega^2)\$ and a first order lag, hence \$G(s)=(s^2+\omega^2)(s+a)\$ giving \$a=7\$ and \$\omega^2=10\$.

Comment: Thanx 2 u sir.... @chu